# Similarity between python string and C character array

Tags: python, c

I was trying to make the connection between python string and C character array assignment to string literals. 
For example:

```
char* word="Hello";
        word="Now";
```

assigns to the character  String "Hello" placed in read only memory location. And now a reassignment of word to "Now" means a now the character array is assigned a memory location corresponding to "Now".

In python even numbers (and obviously strings) seem to work like that with a being assigned a memory location with value 2 and then reassigned a memory location with value 3.

```
 a=2
 a=3
```

This contrasts with C where for almost all variable assignments the variable contains the value it is assigned. Am I making a good comparison here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, `char *` is the type "pointer to character."  A pointer is like a "handle" that gives you access to the value itself.  When you assign `word = "Now";`, you are changing the handle, not the characters of the string.  Both `"Hello"` and `"Now"` still exist as groups of bytes in constant storage.

Python hides more of what it's doing, but internally its built-in string references essentially act like pointers.  So your observation is correct up to a point.

The big difference in strings of these languages is that in Python all strings are immutable.  C lets you manipulate (by assignment) characters within a (non-constant) string.  For example:

```
char word [] = "Hello";
// word is now the name of a 6-character (including final null) mutable string
word[0] = 'h';
// Now word has the value "hello".
```

In Python, you would have to create a completely new string:

```
word = 'h' + word[1:]
```

Here the bytes that make up the new string are different than those of `word`.

You are right that Python has "reference semantics".  Everything behaves as though you are manipulating a handle rather than a value.

```
>>> a=[1]
>>> b=a
>>> a
[1]
>>> b
[1]
>>> a[0]=5
>>> a
[5]
>>> b
[5]
```

Here the assignment `b = a` copied a handle or reference to the list.  The list itself is not copied.  This is evident because changing the first element of `a` also changed `b`.

Comment: I don't see any changes in your output of a and b. They both print [1]. Can you clarify what you mean by change?

Comment: @Joe Baltimore: I fixed the example. I think Gene had a typo. It is a fine example tho. +1

Comment: @JoeBaltimore sorry I made and editing error.  Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: Still if I use char* word="Hello" instead of char word[]="Hello", it becomes immutable like python where I cannot modify anything.

Comment: In all ways that matter this is correct. Literal strings are defined constant by the language. Note though that compilers don't have to put literal strings in read-only storage, so `word[0] = 'h'` might still work. But it's not correct C.

Answer (score 0):

char * means word is a pointer variable.  The address of the string is placed in the variable, the characters in the string don't move.  For C all assignments move a value into the variable, not almost all.  In this case an address is the value being moved.

Python is a little more complex.  It binds the variable to the value which may cause other operations to occur behind the scenes, like freeing the old value.

Comment: Yes, but still it is special because an immutable string is created separately in the memory and then the address is given to char* (not char var[] which makes it possible to change the string contents) variable using the same statement. It is not the case for assignment of other types like int or even char* when it is not assigned to a string.